# Custom color theme not working correctly on Bootstrap, React, SCSS project

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use custom colors with my bootstrap/react/scss setup.  The custom color I'm using is "clear".  Strangely using className="btn-clear" on a button component does make the button in the custom color (correct behaviour), but using className="bg-clear" on a div just leaves the div white, not the custom colour (incorrect behaviour).  So the custom colour appears to be working but only for btn- classes.

Node-sass wasn't building so replaced with sass.

Is it something to do with the order I'm importing modules?

I'm importing custom.scss into my main app using `import '../../scss/custom.scss'`

**custom.scss**

```
@import './vendors/bootstrap';
```

**_bootstrap.scss**

```
// Required
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_variables';

// Import Overrides here
@import 'scss/themes/_bootstrap_overrides';

// Configuration
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_utilities';

@import 'bootstrap/scss/_mixins';

// Layout & components
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_reboot';

@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_type';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_containers';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid'; 
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_forms';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_buttons';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_transitions';

// Helpers
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_helpers';

// Utilities
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/_api';
```

**_bootstrap_overrides.scss**

```
$custom-colors: (
  'gray': $gray-600,
  'clear': #73bae1,
  'clear-light': #c4e2f2,
  'clear-dark': #54a6dc,
);

// Merge with bootstrap theme

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "luxon": "^1.26.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.43.2"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is a bootstrap 5 issue.  Until it's working normally there's a workaround below. [Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34734)

#### _bootstrap.scss

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, (
    'primary-dark' : shade-color($blue, 20%),
    'primary-light' : tint-color($blue, 20%),
    'purple' : $indigo,
    'purple-dark' : shade-color($indigo, 20%),
    'purple-light' : tint-color($indigo, 10%),
));

$utilities-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $utilities-colors);

$utilities-text-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "text");
$utilities-bg-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "bg");
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// and the rest of your Bootstrap components
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this function, then the .bg-clear would work.

```
@mixin color-modifiers($attribute) {
   @each $name, $hex in $custom-colors {
      &-#{$name} {
        #{$attribute}: $hex !important; //important is optional
      }
  }
}

.bg {
  @include color-modifiers(background-color);
}
```